Materialized View with DISTINCT, CURRENT_DATE, JOIN
I'm trying to write a code for Retention Rate on Google Big Query, but I got in my code some functions like count(distinct), current_date(), join which are not supported from Materialized views
Do you know if it's possible to work around with it?

Have you tested using a regular view? Depending on your data/schema/query, perf and resource usage might be acceptable. You still get simplified query access minus MV restrictions. I'd avoid manual workarounds like aggregate tables, etc... The maintenance cost is rarely worth the benefits. Also, BQ MVs are constantly evolving to support more use cases, query shapes, etc... Feel free to create a feature request (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0) or +1 to an existing FR (https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/559654) for what's important to you.
